# robocopy file structure - rename file at destination if its newer

Tags: robocopy

I would like to robocopy a directory and it's subdirectories to another directory. If a file at source is newer then I would like to make a copy of this file by adding a date/time stamp at end of the filename at destination and do the copy to destination.

I do not see any switches in the robocopy to do this. Can someone guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

`Robocopy` doesn't have a renaming switch, but you can use the `rename` command on the resulting files to add timestamps. Here's an example batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=. " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)

dir Directory1\ /b > list
robocopy Directory1\ Backup\
for /f %%f in (list) do rename Backup\%%f %%~nf%mydate%_%mytime%%%~xf
```

Note that you will need to change the delimiters of the date depending on which country standard you follow. You can get that by executing `date /t`

Comment: can you expand on this a little bit more.. can this rename all existing files with the existing f`ilename + yyyymmddhhmmss.txt` for example I understand that RoboCopy does not have an option for rename