# How to copy files based on both name and modified date by batch script

Tags: batch-file

```
robocopy c\a d\a *sql.log*.* /S /D:4/3/2018
```

I am using the above command to copy all the files whose name consists of name sql.log and modified on a particular date.

```
robocopy c\a d\a *sql.log*.* /S
```

If I am using this then it is copying logs with that name but I want to copy logs whose name has sql and modified on a particular date.

Comment: I must be missing something. What is your problem? What are you trying to do with the bottom command that the top command doesn't do?

Comment: with the 2nd command, it is copying all files whose name consists of sql, but i want all files whose name consists of sql and modified on particular date so i am using 1st command but it' giving error

Comment: What error does the first command give? That's important information!

Comment: Are you looking for `*sql*.log`?

Comment: It's giving me error as "invalid number of parameters"

Comment: I am trying to copy all files whose name consists of word 'sql' and modified date is like 4/3/2018

Answer (score 0):

Your command has invalid syntax. There is no option /D in robocopy. I think you misremembered with xcopy. And /d [:date] in xcopy is to copy files changed on or after that date. As I know, robocopy don't have option for renaming files. You should following this link for the instruction.

[robocopy file structure - rename file at destination if its newer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034925/robocopy-file-structure-rename-file-at-destination-if-its-newer)